What servers are considered "processing" by the Sitecore rebuild process?
I'm on Sitecore 10.2 and trying to rebuild our Analytics Database.
I have created a secondary database, but I'm wondering what servers need to be made aware of the new connection string and how exactly to add it.
My ConnectionStrings.config file has a bunch of empty connection strings, and it seems my environment (using AKS) uses environment variables for most of the connection strings.
I get a Connection string used by aggregation/reportingStorageManager/ReportingTargetConfigPath is missing error message when I attempt to start the process.
Thank you.

When you rebuild a reporting database, both the Content Management and Processing Server must have access to the secondary reporting database. The secondary reporting database must be added inside the ConnectionStrings.config file as below.
<addname="reporting.secondary"connectionString="user id=_sql_server_user_;password=_user_password_;Data Source=_sqlserver_;Database= Sitecore_Reporting_Secondary"/>

When we attach a secondary xDB Reporting database to the xDB Processing role, both the primary and secondary xDB Reporting database stores all live aggregation data. This should be only done when you are rebuilding reporting database i.e. starting historical re-aggregation.

When historical re-aggregation gets completed, the secondary xDB Reporting database contains the newly aggregated data, therefore a switch between the secondary and primary xDB Reporting database is required, to ensure the new data is live.
You can find more details for the same here.
https://doc.sitecore.com/xp/en/developers/latest/platform-administration-and-architecture/processing-and-aggregation.html
https://doc.sitecore.com/xp/en/developers/latest/sitecore-experience-platform/rebuild-the-reporting-database.html
Hope this helps!!! Let me know in case you face any issues.
